# allow program to run on guest account mac

Tags: macos, guest-account

How do I allow a program have run access on my guest account?

I am running on a Mac Book pro, I am also running mavericks operating system.

In specific I have installed a game on my admin account. Then I go to the guest account and let my friend play the game. But when I click on the game to load it never loads.

Comment: Does your parental controls limit the apps ?

Comment: I had this problem with a laptop my brothers were using. They couldn't run Minecraft without admin privileges. Oh well.

Comment: @krs013 "Oh well"?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to System Preferences > Parental Controls. There you will see a tab for Apps. From there you select "Limit Applications" if the app you want came from the Mac App Store then look under that triangle for the application and highlight it.

If it was from another source then it will be listed under one of the three other categories.

Select the appropriate app(s) until you are happy with the results and then close the lock on the lower right side.

Comment: This must have changed in Sierra... under Parental Controls there are now only users listed, not apps...